# I have a broken package that will not allow me to perform updates or any changes to my computer. How do I fix it?

Tags: updates, package-management, skype

This is the Error message I get -

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
skype-bin:i386: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
                Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.6.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.6.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
```

Software center will not allow me to install or uninstall any programs, update manager will not update anything.  I have tried from Terminal to use 'apt-get' commands but I hit road blocks there too (as below) for any command I enter.

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Where do I turn next?  How do I fix this?

Note: I could care less if I have to get rid of Skype, I rarely use it and have another computer it works on anyways.

Answer (score 1):

```
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

For this problem , reason is simple . you must be root while doing this & to be a root , place `sudo` before the command you are typing . for example to update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

while coming to your first issue . open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

hope that helps .

Answer (score 0):

I suppose part of the answer is contained in the error message output by apt-get already: apt-get operations have to be called as root. So you should try 
`sudo apt-get ...`, which will ask you for your password and then execute as root (if your user privileges allow this).

In your case, if you don't care for skype anyway, try:

```
  sudo apt-get remove skype-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you had Skype from Ubuntu installed in then from the website (or vice-versa). Remove Skype completely

```
sudo apt-get purge skype*
```

and then install the Skype version that you want to use.